# How to create subfolders and files if not present inside a script without multiple mkdir?

Tags: shell, logging

What is a better way to create sub folders in a shell script? Instead of using the following method?

`mkdir /var/log
mkdir /var/log/celery
mkdir /var/log/celery/stdout
mkdir /var/log/celery/stderr
touch /var/log/celery/stdout/stdout.log <<< I'm hoping the use this path create folder if doesn't exists....
touch /var/log/celery/stderr/stderr.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mkdir` has a `-p` flag that will create parent directories but `touch` will not create directories that do not exist.

That still cuts the above down to:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/celery/stdout /var/log/celery/stderr
touch /var/log/celery/stdout/stdout.log /var/log/celery/stderr/stderr.log
```

Which in a shell that supports brace expansion could even be:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/celery/{stdout,stderr}
touch /var/log/celery/{stdout/stdout.log,stderr/stderr.log}
```

And actually, if you have brace expansion but not `mkdir -p` you could do:

```
mkdir /var/log{,/celery{,/{stdout,stderr}}}
touch /var/log/celery/{stdout/stdout.log,stderr/stderr.log}
```

But there isn't any way to combine the `mkdir` and `touch` steps with standard tools that I'm aware of.

Comment: This is far more elegant! Thank you!

Comment: readline will even expand a glob into a brace expansion for you with `complete-into-braces` which is bound to `M-{` by default. Not that that is useful here but it is neat.

Answer (score 1):

The `-p` option of `mkdir` will create the intermediate folders of the path if they don't exists (and of course, if you have the appropriate privileges):

```
mkdir -p /var/log/celery/stderr
```

To create the file, you can append the `touch` after the operator `&&`, so the touch operation only occurs if the directory either was created successfully or already exists:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/celery/stderr && touch "$_/stderr.log"
```

(Basically, the `$_` will pass the dir path to the `touch` command)

Comment: thanks! but what about the .log file? I want to create the path and file in one in conjunction instead of it separate.

Comment: The use of `$_` there is clever. Though typo-ed.

Comment: It should also be noted that `$_` is not a standard shell special parameter.  It is a Korn Shell extension and is also available in Korn Shell compatible shells, including Bash.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

```
 $ needir () { mkdir -p $1; echo $1; }

 $ touch $(needir /var/log/celery/stderr)/stderr.log
```

and put "needir" in your .profile, or better yet, in a function library on your path that you source when you login.  you'd be surprised how often you'll be using it.